# PostgresSQL Row level security

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

- Trip

```
create table trips (
  id SERIAL,
  admin_id uuid references auth.users not null,
  

  primary key (id)
);
```

- Guests (has reference to trip)

```
create table trip_guests (
  -- email that is guest of the trip:
  email text,
  
  -- Trip id
  trip_id varchar(100) not null,
  
  -- User right
  user_right_for_trip user_right not null default 'guest',
  
  primary key (email, trip_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_trip_email_id FOREIGN KEY (trip_id) REFERENCES trips (id)
);
```

I would like to use `row level security` from `Postgres` to only grant access to select methods (`creator trip add user guest`).

But I struggle a bit doing it in an idiomatic way.
I've only managed to achieve what I want by creating an array inside the primary table `Trips` that keeps track of `guests id`. But it seems and I feel that it is not the most idiomatic way of doing it in SQL language.

Because when using `row level security` it seems that I can only return a single row:

```
alter table trips enable row level security;

create policy "Only trip creator or guests of a trip are allowed to select"
  on trips for select
  using ( auth.email()=function_that_cross_guests_table() OR admin_id = auth.uid() );
```

The above query only returns a single row and not all the rows where the user is a `guest` or `creator of a trip`.
This is because the function in 'using' expression can only return a single row.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you describe the SQL condition that identifies a guest or an administrator? You need to be able to do that somehow to use RLS.

Comment: Actually, the main pain point is that when pick the 'using' expression, I can only use function but the function can only return a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to do it!

Thanks to this link:
https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/using-row-level-security-to-make-large-companies-more-secure/

```
create policy "Only trip creator or guests of a trip are allowed to get"
  on trips for select
  using ( id IN (select trip_id from trip_guests where email = auth.email()) OR admin_id = auth.uid() );
```

Comment: Sure, all you need to do is come up with a "`WHERE` condition" for who is allowed. Take care of the performance impact of complicated policy definitions. In particular, that `OR` may wreck performance for each query on the table. Test with realistic amounts of data!